# How to set the title to the RadioButtons

Tags: cocoa, radio-button

I have create a radio group in the xib and mapped with IBOutlet.
Now what i want to do is to set the title to the each radio button in the group.

i tried doing like this in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching method

```
NSArray *cells = [myRadio cells];
[[cells objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"First radio"]; and so on for 4 radio's.
```

Can anyone help me how to set the title for the radio button's dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

First connect `radioGroup` (`IBOutlet`) to the `NSMatrix`.
Next update the title like this:

```
[[radioGroup cellAtRow:0 column:0] setTitle:@"First Radio"]; 
[[radioGroup cellAtRow:1 column:0] setTitle:@"Second Radio"];
```

Or like this:

```
[[radioGroup cellWithTag:0] setTitle:@"Radio with tag zero"];
```

Comment: This certainly works, make sure the `IBoutlet` is connected correctly to the `NSMatrix`.